# show images in a listview stored in hashmap android

Tags: java, android, mysql

I am making an Android application where I catch data from a mySQL database via PHP and JSON, I want an image is displayed according to the data of the database in a listview, this data is stored on a hash map:

```
HashMap <String, String> resultp = new HashMap <String, String> ();
resultp = data.get(position);
public ListViewAdapter(Context context,
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
            this.context = context;
            data = arraylist;

        }

resultp.get (MainActivity.PUBLIC); this gives me the position, I want the data. How I can do?
when I change resultp.get (MainActivity.PUBLIC)  for the name of a resource of my project it works

if (image != null) {
                 Resources res = context.getResources ();
                 String Sicon = "com.resources.hashmap: drawable /" + resultp.get (MainActivity.PUBLIC);
                 int id = context.getResources () getIdentifier (Sicon, "drawable" context.getPackageName ());
               
                 imagen.setImageResource (id);
             }
```

Comment: You have to implement your Custom List View and respective adapter to display images in ListView. A better method is to use Recycler View with Card View.

Answer (score 0):

Here are good references by which you can clearly understand how to play with custom lists and array adapters.

[Example 1](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/)
[Example 2](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92)
[Example 3](http://www.androidinterview.com/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/)